# Python MemoryError When Querying ArcGIS Web Service

Tags: python, python-2.7, gis, arcgis

I am running into the following MemoryError when running the below script. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The layer that I am querying contains 235,896 features which I'm afraid is the problem.

**Script**

```
import arcgis
import json

from arcgis import ArcGIS
service = ArcGIS("http://mapping.dekalbcountyga.gov/arcgis/rest/services/LandUse/MapServer")
query = service.get(0, count_only=False)
json_query = json.dump(query)
f = open("dekalb_parcels.geojson", "w")
f.write(json_query)
f.close()
```

**Error**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "G:/Python/Scripts/dekalb_parcel_query.py", line 8, in <module>
        query = service.get(0, count_only=False)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\arcgis\arcgis.py", line 146, in get
        jsobj = self.get_json(layer, where, fields, count_only, srid)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\arcgis\arcgis.py", line 90, in get_json
        return response.json(strict=False)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 802, in json
        return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 769, in text
        content = str(self.content, encoding, errors='replace')
    MemoryError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to rectify this issue by switching to 64-bit Python. The process was crashing when it reached 2GB of RAM usage, but by switching to 64-bit Python I avoided this problem.